# Kentico V8.2 to V9.0 upgrade missing ~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx

Tags: upgrade, kentico

I'm recently going through my first Kentico upgrade on a site that was previously handed to me from somebody else. There were some hinks initially, but I have to say the V8.2 to V9.0 upgrade is gone off with a degree of success. There is one last issue I'm tackling. Initially the issue was with images stored in the database, but I resolved that with setting custom URL extensions. The style sheet we have in the database is returning a 404, so the entire site is without style.

I did some digging, and found the following:

- While we were using ~/CMSPages/GetCSS.aspx in V8.2, that appears to have been deprecated/obsolete for some time now. The CSS references in the master page all point to ~/CMSPages/GetCSS.aspx.
- In V8.2, I can confirm the presence of ~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx, but that appears to be missing after the V9.0 upgrade. I installed a blank template site as well to confirm, and it's not there either. I verified I am using the latest upgrade package. I had already hit an issue with the pre-12/15 edition.
- The V8.2 ~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx does not work in a V9.0 as the API for CMS.UIControls no longer contains the ResourceHandler class (which is also used in ~/CMSPages/GetCSS.aspx).
- I can confirm in the V8.2 codebase that ~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx works, returning the specified stylesheet.

**TL;DR** - Upgrading from V8.2 to V9.0, I appear to be missing ~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx, and am not sure where it got off to.

---

Environment Information

Test Server: Windows Server 2008R2 SP1 on IIS 7.5 w/ .NET 4.5.2, MSSQL 2008R2 Database backend

Dev Server: Windows 8.1 with IIS 8.5, VS 2015 and MSSQL 2008R2
Kentico V8.2 Site in Portal Mode

I appreciate any ideas you have.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick update, I tried going through the upgrade again, and I am still running into the 404's for ~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx. I am going to test on a new template site to see if it's an issue with the upgrade.

Comment: Update: Apparently I was doing something wrong in the upgrade, I haven't been able to reproduce after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving a 404 on GetResource.ashx in v8 when deploying my site.  I have my site setup as a web application. My problem was I was only deploying CMSApp using Visual Studio. I needed to also deploy CMSApp_AppCode. https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Publishing+web+application+projects+from+Visual+Studio

when I upgraded to v9 from v8.2 I was getting a 500 Error on GetResource.ashx. After my upgrade I just re-deployed. I don't know what the issue was, but getting the errors, I cleared out all the files on the Azure server then deployed. This fixed my error.

Maybe one of these two items will help you.

Comment: sorry for the delay, but this was closest to what ended up solving my issue, I just repeated the upgrade, and made sure my url extensions were set (they didn't appear to be coming over, but that was an easier fix for me)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the `.ashx` were moved to the `CMS.UIControls` assembly and adjusted to implement `IHttpHandler`.

This way the handlers can be used by any application that references the Kentico libraries, specifically the UIControls. This approach has been utilized e.g. in the [new MVC support in Kentico 9](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+page+attachments+in+MVC+applications).

If you need to customize the handlers you can take advantage of the `GetFileHandler` and `AdvancedGetFileHandler` abstract classes implementing `IHttpHandler`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rocky. Thanks for this information. I may have misstated the problem I'm seeing, and for that I apologize. Here is a screenshot of a [Fiddler Session](http://imgur.com/G84yHMw) where stage is V8.2, and the others are V9.0. I don't think I need to customize the handlers, I'm assuming, based off this [Kentico Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Designing+websites+using+CSS). So I'm wondering why I'm seeing the 404's.

Comment: No, you don't need to customize the handlers. This should indeed work. Can you check whether your DLLs have been upgraded correctly? Look at the properties of the `CMS.UIControls.dll` assembly and check that the version is 9.0.*. Also check whether your application (if you have any custom code) adds anything to `System.Web.Routing.RoutingTable.Routes` that could collide with CMSPages/Get*.ashx and cause the 404s. I would also have a look into the `CMS_DocumentAlias` SQL table and check for any suspicious routes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I checked `CMS.UIControls.dll`, and it upgraded, and I did a spot check on others, JIC, and they are all at 9.0.*. We weren't using any routing in our custom code (Web Forms), but just for the sake of thoroughness, I checked ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs to see if something had got into there, with no luck. While there were a lot of entries in `CMS_DocumentAlias`, I didn't see any suspicious routes that had "GetResource" in the `AliasURLPath` or `AliasExtensions` field, but to no avail.

Comment: Then, I'd go to IIS -> Handler mappings and check whether *.ashx are enabled. + Do you use extensionless urls? (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Extensionless+and+custom+URLs)

Comment: I wanted to reply back and say that apparently it was an issue in my upgrade. I did it again, and haven't been able to repeat the issue. Thank you so much for your information, it was a big help!

Answer (score 0):

If I read the release notes correctly, they moved the files to the UIControls library and you can still utilize the old references without issue.  I've upgraded my website from 8.0.48 to 9.0.1 and 9.0.4 and had no issues.  In fact, I still use the `/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=/path/to/file.js`  I believe the change was specifically to accommodate the MVC model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Brenden. Hmmm...So I'm curious why I receive a 404 with the V9.0 code vs the V8.2 code. Would it be a setting? If the change was to accommodate the MVC model, would it be in the routing? I'm not sure where the routing is handled in Kentico. Here is a Fiddler session. Stage is V8.2, the rest are V9.0. [Fiddler Session](http://imgur.com/G84yHMw) Sorry for all the edits, the image tagging wasn't working for me.